# Pointers, chars and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, char, scanf

Im having problems with the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
char *pointer;
int num, i;
printf_s("Enter number of elements: ");
scanf_s("%d", &num);
pointer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * num);
for (i = 0; i < num; i++, pointer++)
    scanf_s(" %c", pointer);
pointer -= num;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
printf_s("%c", *(pointer + i));
free(pointer);
return 0;
}
```

the code is fairly simple ,and all i want to do is print characters that i just entered. Instead, it prints nothing/whitespace. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the advice already given...

The following comes from the documentation for `scanf_s`

Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in [].

In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:

```
char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: much appreciated, that solved it. but, if im using a for loop to enter, say, 3 elements, should i put the buffer size to 3?  `printf_s("Enter number of elements: ");
scanf_s("%d", &num);
pointer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * num);
for (i = 0; i < num; i++, pointer++)
scanf_s(" %c", pointer, num); `

Comment: Since you are converting one character at a time, the buffer size should be specified as 1, `scanf_s( "%c", pointer, 1 )`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
scanf_s(" %c");
```

To:

```
scanf_s("%c");
```

And while you're at it (although not directly related to the problem at hand), get rid of the `malloc`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    scanf_s("%c", &c);
    printf_s("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any why the `malloc`?

Comment: @Ed Heal: Yep, got me just before I committed that note (although not directly related to the problem).

Comment: thank you, but what if i wanted to create a array, say of n elements, we learned that it's done like 'pointer = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char) * n)'. I used a for loop to enter elements, but the problem persisted. also, i wanted a pointer variable (not a regular one) to be in the scanf, so that a character that i enter is put where the pointer points, and then print it.

Comment: @MoSFeT Why don't you just declared an array on stack like this `char str[N]` ?

Comment: @MoSFeT, if you want an array of `n` characters (where `n` is computed only during runtime), then yes - you would need to use `malloc`. This is not the case here, however, as you only have a single character. Regarding your other question - `scanf` takes an adress in any case (whether you declare `char c` and call `scanf` with `&c`, or declare `char* p` and call `scanf` with `p`).

Comment: @mr5 as barak mentioned, i need to compute n during runtime, as for my problem, its still printing blank characters when i remove space from scanf, im gonna post a updated version

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the `malloc` (even though Barak answer is correct)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main(void)
{
    char x;
    scanf_s("%c", &x);
    printf_s("%c", x);
    return 0;
}
```